# Extracting part of a file path, to insert as a variable in a new column, within a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, merge, filenames, strsplit

I am trying to create a *merged data frame* (to be written as master-adh-merge_datestamp.csv) from individual source files (.csv).

Each individual source file contains data pertaining a specific month. I am using a loop function to allow me to iterate the *merged data frame* as each new month's data becomes available.

Within the created *merged data frame*, i want to add a column which denotes the date from which the obs are from. I want to strip the date from the filename string of that month's source file. The file names for the source files are standardised "adh-merged_YYYYY-MM-DD.csv" and all held in the same folder "~/Google Drive/My Drive/PhD/CFHH_Monthly_Extracts/trial/Merges". I want to write the iterative master-merge document to the folder ""~/Google Drive/My Drive/PhD/CFHH_Monthly_Extracts/trial/master-merges"

This is my current code to try and create and write this *merged data frame* as a .csv file.

```
ROOT.DIR <- "~/Google Drive/My Drive/PhD/CFHH_Monthly_Extracts/trial"
ROOT.DIR.MERGES <- paste0(ROOT.DIR, "/Merges")
files <- list.files(ROOT.DIR.MERGES, all.files=TRUE,full.names=TRUE)
master_adh_merge <- vector()
for(i in files){
  print(i)
  df <- read.csv(i)
  master_adh_merge <- rbind (master_adh_merge,df)
}

datestamp <- Sys.Date()
datestamp <- format(x = datestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
write.csv(master_adh_merge, paste0(ROOT.DIR, "/master-merge", "/master-adh-merge_", datestamp, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
```

I successfully ran this code yesterday, but the master-adh-merge_datestamp.csv file had the entire file path as new column value for each row.

**Question 1**

I am trying to find some code to put within the `for(i in files){}` loop to extract just the YYYY-MM-DD from the source file path and name (rather than the whole file path and name) and put in a a column for all obs derived from that source file within the *merged data frame* (to allow me to analyse data by month).

I have tried `gsub` and `sub` within the loop, but this is my first attempt at using loops and i cannot seem to get it to work.

**Question 2**

Today, i have run the loop again but am getting this result and a new error, which i did not get when i ran the loop yesterday.

[1] "/Users/Rob/Google Drive/My Drive/PhD/CFHH_Monthly_Extracts/trial/Merges/adh-merged_2021-01-01.csv"
[1] "/Users/Rob/Google Drive/My Drive/PhD/CFHH_Monthly_Extracts/trial/Merges/adh-merged_2021-02-01.csv"
[1] "/Users/Rob/Google Drive/My Drive/PhD/CFHH_Monthly_Extracts/trial/Merges/Icon\r"
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
no lines available in input

That the loop is identifying the first 2 files there correctly, and they are the only two files within the ""/Users/Rob/Google Drive/My Drive/PhD/CFHH_Monthly_Extracts/trial/Merges" folder

I am not sure why the loop is trying to include this file "/Users/Rob/Google Drive/My Drive/PhD/CFHH_Monthly_Extracts/trial/Merges/Icon\r", as "/Icon\r" does not exist within the folder "/Users/Rob/Google Drive/My Drive/PhD/CFHH_Monthly_Extracts/trial/Merges". Is "/Icon\r" a hidden folder or file which is created when running any loop?

If anyone can help me here it would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it would be nice if you could provide some code in the future with the exisiting dataframe or rather how to construct two-three rows or so of your dataframe/the relevant columns, as this makes testing code for answers muche easier. The more specific you are and show your already done work, the quicker you will get the solution (of course, if given, sensitive data should be replaced by you).

Regarding question 1:

Ideally you already have all the filenames (with the complete path) in a dataframe, e.g., in a column called `existing_column`. From there you can use all of the proposed solution here very easily by just using, e.g., `mutate(df, new_column = gsub("/Users/Rob/Google Drive/My Drive/PhD/CFHH_Monthly_Extracts/trial/Merges/adh-merged_(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).csv", "\\1", exisiting_column)`. If you have the file names in a vector/list and want to loop over them you can do that, too, but it's going to be less efficient and doesn't seem to be required here (apart from much more complicated code than necessary). If you want to extract the date but want to get rid of the path to the file and the extension, there are multiple ways you can approach this:

1. `str_replace()`: This method is the least flexible (and arguably least elegant) solution but the easiest one to write and understand. It will only work if you are sure the filenames' naming pattern won't change. You could go about this problem by using `str_replace()` to first replace
   the substring `"/Users/Rob/Google Drive/My Drive/PhD/CFHH_Monthly_Extracts/trial/Merges/adh-merged_"` from `"/Users/Rob/Google Drive/My Drive/PhD/CFHH_Monthly_Extracts/trial/Merges/adh-merged_2021-02-01.csv"` with `""` (nothing). You are left with `"2021-02-01.csv"` and can now apply `str_replace()` again to replace `".csv"` with `""` (nothing). You are left with the date as desired.
2. `gsub()` (like you had already mentioned): The path and naming pattern shouldn't change (or you should take care of those things with, e.g., `paste()` or `sprintf()`:

   `your.path <- "/Users/Rob/Google Drive/My Drive/PhD/CFHH_Monthly_Extracts/trial/Merges/adh-merged_2021-02-01.csv"`

   `gsub("/Users/Rob/Google Drive/My Drive/PhD/CFHH_Monthly_Extracts/trial/Merges/adh-merged_(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).csv", "\\1", your.path)`
3. `basename()`: Use `basename()` on the path to get the filename and then use option 1. or 2. and modify it to to take care of the file extension `".csv"`.
4. `str_extract()`: This is probably optimal but can sometimes be a little less beginner-friendly and would require a dataframe for testing (ideally yours or a snippet/head of yours like mentioned above). The other solutions should work fine, though.

Regarding question 2:

Check if you are in the correct working directory and use `file.exists()` and `dir.exists()` to verify that the paths you provide are recognized by the program.